# how does the lower recursion works in the code?

Tags: python

```
def isPal(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        print(s)

    else:
         print(s)
         s[0] == s[-1] and isPal((s[1:-1]))
         print(s)
    print("HI")
x = isPal("deleveled")
print(x)
```

Output:

```
deleveled
elevele
level
eve
v
HI
eve
HI
level
HI
elevele
HI
deleveled
HI
None
```

Comment: need explanation on how HI eve HI level HI elevele HI deleveled HI None outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break down the program.

Firstly, if the string given to isPal() is one or zero characters, it's printed. In other words, once we can't simplify any more, we stop simplifying and just output what we have.

Otherwise (when we have two or more characters), we check that the first and last character are equal, and then perform the same algorithm on the string without these two characters. This continues until we have one or zero characters, as described above.

The reason the word is rebuilding at the end is that you have printed the string again after your recursive function call. So after going 'deeper' into your word, you print where you came from too.

EDIT: The reason 'HI' is printed is that after you've done your going 'deeper' into the word and have come back out, you print 'HI' each time. So every time you take one step back out of the program (one more letter back at the start and end), you print 'HI'.

I think the issue with your code is that you've not actually told the function to answer the 'isPal' question with a True or False.

```
def isPal(s):
    if len(s) <= 1:
        print(s)
        return True

    else:
         print(s)
         return (s[0] == s[-1] and isPal((s[1:-1])))
x = isPal("deleveled")
print(x)
```

This code will now return True or False depending on whether your algorithm detects that the string is a palindrome or not.

Your code actually did what you wanted it to, you just hadn't returned the result of your check.

Comment: Hi Reece need to know how the output derived from HI
eve
HI
level
HI
elevele
HI
deleveled
HI

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain the 'HI's as well. It's about how you run those print statements after your recursive call.

Comment: I understood the upper recursive call but  need to know how the lower recursive call work as ( eve - level - level - deleveled ) is formed ?

Comment: I see. So it's important to realise that you aren't 'forming' ( eve - level - level - deleveled ), you are simply remembering it. Your print(s) statement after the recursive call just prints the current value. So while the recursive call is going 'deeper' into your word, the current state of the word is still the same, so when the recursive call is done, the word is simply printed as it was before you entered the recursive call, which gives the effect of 'building' the word back up, when in fact you are simply remembering and reversing the process of breaking the word down.

Comment: This about it this way: you do three things in order. First, you print the word. Second, you do your recursive call. Third, you print the word. Now, in that second step, you will cut letters off the word and do these three steps over and over, but we don't actually need to worry about the details there. The point is, that recursive call is wedged between two print statements, which simply print the word in its current state. And since the recursive call creates a new version of the word, the original version remains the same and is printed again in the third step.

Comment: nice Reece but the word is simply printed as it was before you entered the recursive call, so how does it remember correctly the previous recursive call? it is amazing!

Comment: It is amazing! What happens is the computer saves the original state of the word in the 'stack' (part of the computer's memory), then it will create a new version of the word which is used in the recursive call. When the recursive call is complete, it looks at the stack to get the original value of the word.

Comment: It really is! If you found this answer helped you, you can mark it as correct by clicking the tick, which will help others in the community see the most helpful responses if they have a similar question.